# Swift 4.0 Difference between implementing custom operator inside a type as a type method and in global scope as a global function

Tags: swift, functional-programming

Given a Parser type as following:

```
public struct Parser<Result> {
  internal let parse: (String) -> (Result, String)?

  public func run(_ string: String) -> (Result, String)? {
    guard let (result, remainder) = parse(string) else { return nil }
    return (result, remainder)
  }

  public func map<T>(_ transform: @escaping (Result) -> T )
    -> Parser<T> {
      return Parser<T> { input in
        guard let (result, remainder) = self.run(input) else { return nil }
        return (transform(result), remainder)
      }
  }

  public func followed<A>(by other: Parser<A>) -> Parser<(Result, A)> {
    return Parser<(Result, A)> {  input in
      guard let (result, remainder) = self.run(input) else { return nil }
      guard let (resultA, remainderA) = other.run(remainder) else { return nil }
      return ((result, resultA), remainderA)
    }
  }
}
```

First implementation as following:

```
infix operator >>> : FunctionCompositionPrecedence
public func >>> <A, B> (lhs: Parser<A>, rhs: Parser<B>) 
  -> Parser<(A,B)> {
  return lhs.followed(by: rhs)
}
```

Second implementation as following:

```
infix operator >>> : FunctionCompositionPrecedence
extension Parser {
  public static func >>> <A, B> (lhs: Parser<A>, rhs: Parser<B>) 
    -> Parser<(A,B)> {
    return lhs.followed(by: rhs)
  }
}
```

Reclaim the question as what is the difference between the first implementation and the second one.

Moreover, when I use the first implementation, and compile the following code, the compiler reported an error as 
**"'map' produces 'Parser', not the expected contextual result type 'Parser'"**

```
extension Parser {
  public static func apply <A, B> (_ lhs: Parser<(A)->B>, _ rhs: Parser<A>) -> Parser<B> {
    return (lhs >>> rhs).map{(arg) -> B in let (f, x) = arg; return f(x)}
  }
}
```

However, after I use the second implementation, everything goes fine.
I am so confused about the essential nuances between them.

Comment: I presumed "*when I use the first implementation, and compile the following code, the compiler reported an error*" was a typo and that you're actually talking about the second implementation, right? The first compiles just fine for me along with `apply(_:_:)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

> ```
> infix operator >>> : FunctionCompositionPrecedence
> extension Parser {
>   public static func >>> <A, B> (lhs: Parser<A>, rhs: Parser<B>) 
>     -> Parser<(A,B)> {
>     return lhs.followed(by: rhs)
>   }
> }
> ```

You've provided no way for the compiler to infer the generic placeholder `Result` on calling the operator (really I think the compiler should error here rather than on usage). Remember that static methods on generic types are called on *specialisations* of those types; the placeholders must be satisfied (as they're accessible at static scope).

So to directly answer

> what is the difference between the first implementation and the second one.

The main difference is that as a static member, you have the additional generic placeholder `Result` that needs to be satisfied; as a top-level function, you don't have that.

So, if you want to keep `>>>` as a static method, you'll want to use the `Result` placeholder in the signature of your operator implementation such that the compiler can infer its type on usage, for example:

```
infix operator >>> : FunctionCompositionPrecedence
extension Parser {

  public static func >>> <B> (
    lhs: Parser, rhs: Parser<B> 
  ) -> Parser<(Result, B)> {
      return lhs.followed(by: rhs)
  }
}
```

Now `Result` can be inferred from the type of the argument passed as the `lhs` of the operator (`Parser` is syntactic sugar for `Parser<Result>` in this context).

Note you'll face a similar problem with

> ```
> extension Parser {
>   public static func apply <A, B> (_ lhs: Parser<(A)->B>, _ rhs: Parser<A>) -> Parser<B> {
>     return (lhs >>> rhs).map{(arg) -> B in let (f, x) = arg; return f(x)}
>   }
> }
> ```

in that you'll need to explicitly satisfy the `Result` placeholder when calling; although the type used to satisfy it won't actually be used by the method.

Better would be to use the `Result` placeholder in the signature to allow the compiler to infer it at the call-site:

```
extension Parser {

  public static func apply<Arg>(
    _ lhs: Parser<(Arg) -> Result>, _ rhs: Parser<Arg>
  ) -> Parser<Result> {

    return (lhs >>> rhs).map { arg -> Result in
      let (f, x) = arg
      return f(x)
    }
  }
}

// ...

let p = Parser<(String) -> String> { input in ({ $0 + input }, "hello") }
let p1 = Parser { ($0, "") }

let p2 = Parser.apply(p, p1)
print(p2.run(" world") as Any) // Optional(("hello world", ""))
```

Or, better still, as an instance method:

```
extension Parser {

  public func apply<A, B>(with rhs: Parser<A>) -> Parser<B>
    where Result == (A) -> B {

    return (self >>> rhs).map { arg -> B in
      let (f, x) = arg
      return f(x)
    }
  }
}

// ...

let p = Parser<(String) -> String> { input in ({ $0 + input }, "hello") }
let p1 = Parser { ($0, "") }

let p2 = p.apply(with: p1)
print(p2.run(" world") as Any) // Optional(("hello world", ""))
```

Comment: Wow. It truly makes sense. I was so silly that I hadn't thought about that. Thank you very much. I will take an experiment on your reasoning. Thanks again.