# understanding protocol extensions in swift

Tags: swift, protocols, protocol-extension

I am trying to implement a basic protocol extension like so:

```
protocol Value {
    func get() -> Float
    mutating func set(to:Float)
}
extension Value {
    static func min(of a:Value, and b:Value) -> Float {
        if a < b { //Expression type 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context
            return a.get()
        }else{
            return b.get()
        }
    }
    static func < (a:Value, b:Value) -> Bool {
        return a.get() < b.get()
    }
}
```

At the `if` clause the compiler says:`Expression type 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context`. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: move`func < (a:Value, b:Value) -> Bool` in a global context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As touched on [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47571798/2976878), there's a difference between operator overloads implemented as `static` members and operator overloads implemented as top-level functions. `static` members take an additional (implicit) `self` parameter, which the compiler needs to be able to infer.

So how is the value of `self` inferred? Well, it has to be done from either the operands or return type of the overload. For a protocol extension, this means one of those types needs to be `Self`. Bear in mind that you can't directly call an operator on a type (i.e you can't say `(Self.<)(a, b)`).

Consider the following example:

```
protocol Value {
  func get() -> Float
}

extension Value {
  static func < (a: Value, b: Value) -> Bool {
    print("Being called on conforming type: \(self)")
    return a.get() < b.get()
  }
}

struct S : Value {
  func get() -> Float { return 0 }
}

let value: Value = S()
print(value < value) // Ambiguous reference to member '<'
```

What's the value of `self` in the call to `<`? The compiler can't infer it (really I think it should error directly on the overload as it's un-callable). Bear in mind that `self` at static scope in a protocol extension must be a *concrete* conforming type; it can't just be `Value.self` (as static methods in protocol extensions are only available to call on concrete conforming types, not on the protocol type itself).

We can fix both the above example, and your example by defining the overload as a top-level function instead:

```
protocol Value {
  func get() -> Float
}

func < (a: Value, b: Value) -> Bool {
  return a.get() < b.get()
}

struct S : Value {
  func get() -> Float { return 0 }
}

let value: Value = S()
print(value < value) // false
```

This works because now we don't need to infer a value for `self`.

We could have also given the compiler a way to infer the value of `self`, by making one or both of the parameters take `Self`:

```
protocol Value {
  func get() -> Float
}

extension Value {
  static func < (a: Self, b: Self) -> Bool {
    print("Being called on conforming type: \(self)")
    return a.get() < b.get()
  }
}

struct S : Value {
  func get() -> Float { return 0 }
}

let s = S()
print(s < s)

//  Being called on conforming type: S
//  false
```

The compiler can now infer `self` from the static type of operands. However, as said above, this needs to be a concrete type, so you can't deal with *heterogenous* `Value` operands (you could work with one operand taking a `Value`; but not both as then there'd be no way to infer `self`).

---

Although note that if you're providing a default implementation of `<`, you should probably also provide a default implementation of `==`. Unless you have a good reason not to, I would also advise you make these overloads take homogenous concrete operands (i.e parameters of type `Self`), such that they can provide a default implementation for `Comparable`.

Also rather than having `get()` and `set(to:)` requirements, I would advise a settable property requirement instead:

```
// Not deriving from Comparable could be useful if you need to use the protocol as
// an actual type; however note that you won't be able to access Comparable stuff,
// such as the auto >, <=, >= overloads from a protocol extension.
protocol Value {
  var floatValue: Double { get set }
}

extension Value {

  static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    return lhs.floatValue == rhs.floatValue
  }

  static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    return lhs.floatValue < rhs.floatValue
  }
}
```

Finally, if `Comparable` conformance is essential for conformance to `Value`, you should make it derive from `Comparable`:

```
protocol Value : Comparable {
  var floatValue: Double { get set }
}
```

You shouldn't need a `min(of:and:)` function in either case, as when the conforming type conforms to `Comparable`, it can use the top-level `min(_:_:)` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write

```
if a < b {
```

because `a` and `b` have type `Value` which is NOT `Comparable`.

However you can compare the `float` value associated to `a` and `b`

```
if a.get() < b.get() {
```

Comment: So defining the static function `<` for `Value` does not make them comparable?

Comment: @gloo There are several reasons why it will not work. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334684/how-do-i-implement-swifts-comparable-protocol).

Comment: "So defining the static function < for Value does not make them comparable" No, it does not. Protocols are not adopted implicitly. You have to declare adoption explicitly. You would then _still_ need a definition of `<` of course.

Comment: You *can* write a `<` overload without conforming the operands to `Comparable` (just not the reverse). OP's problem is a bit more subtle; their implementation of the overload as a `static` member isn't valid because they haven't given the compiler a way to infer `self`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to make types that can use operators such as `>`, `<`, `==`, etc., they have to conform to the `Comparable` protocol:

```
 protocol Value: Comparable {
    func get() -> Float
    mutating func set(to: Float)
}
```

This comes with more restrictions though. You will have to change all the `Value` types in the protocol extension to `Self`:

```
extension Value {
    static func min(of a: Self, and b: Self) -> Float {
        if a < b { //Expression type 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context
            return a.get()
        }else{
            return b.get()
        }
    }

    static func < (a: Self, b: Self) -> Bool {
        return a.get() < b.get()
    }
}
```

The `Self` types get replaced with the type that implements the protocol. So if I implemented `Value` on a type `Container`, the methods signatures would look like this:

```
class Container: Value {
    static func min(of a: Container, and b: Container) -> Float

    static func < (a: Container, b: Container) -> Bool
}
```

As a side note, if you want `Value` to conform to `Comparable`, you might want to also add the `==` operator to the `Value` extension:

```
static func <(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    return lhs.get() < rhs.get()
}
```